# passing props between React components with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to pass useToggle custom Hook props to a button in `<DrawerToggleButton/>` component, and i need help

i have imported useToggler hook in App, and i have pass props with spread operator in `<Header/>` component

```
const App = () => {
    const [show, toggle]=useToggler();

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Header {...toggle} />
            <SideDrawer/>
            <Backdrop/>
            <main style={{marginTop:'56px'}}>
                <p>Page content</p>
            </main>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Then i have tried to pass the props in `<DrawerToggleButton/>`, and i dont know if this is fine..

```
const Header: React.FC = (props) => {
    return (
        <header className="toolbar">
            <nav className="toolbar—navigation">
                <DrawerToggleButton {...props}/>
                <div className="toolbar—logo"><a href="">Logo</a></div>
                <div className="spacer"></div>
                <div className="toolbar—items">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">LogIn</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">SignUp</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
    )
};

export default Header
```

My goal is to make onClick property to work....

```
onst DrawerToggleButton: React.FC = () => {



    return (
        <button className="toggle—button" onClick={?}>
            <div className="toggle—button—line">{}</div>
            <div className="toggle—button—line"></div>
            <div className="toggle—button—line"></div>
        </button>
    )
};

export default DrawerToggleButton
```

toggle is clickHandler function:

```
function useToggler (defaultOnValue=false):[boolean, ()=>void]{
    const [isToggled,setIsToggled]=useState(defaultOnValue);

    function clickHandler(){
        setIsToggled((prev)=>!prev)
    }
    return[isToggled, clickHandler]
}

export default useToggler
```

Comment: what is `toggle`? Is it a `Iterable`?

Comment: Why didn't you add `props` to component `DrawerToggleButton` function arguments? Also have you simply tried logging props (after you add `props` to `DrawerToggleButton`) and see what happens?

Comment: I have tried but it doesn't work...

Comment: A couple of things, firstly `setIsToggled`, I think should just be `setIsToggled(!isToggled)` - in your situation you're setting it to a function that returns the opposite of its argument. In terms of what else might not be working, your `useToggle` hook returns `show` which I presume you want to use to hide/show something, but you're not using it. You're also trying to destructure `{...toggle}` - `toggle` is a clickHandler, so you can't do this, just pass it in like a normal prop. `handleOnClick={toggle}` or something like that.

Comment: @BrettEast `setIsToggled(prev => !prev)` is actually the preferred way here. If you provide a function to the `useState` setter, it basically transforms the previous value into the next state to circumvent a race condition that might occur if the state way changed in between the read and set in `setState`

Comment: @Linschlager interesting, I didn't realise you could pass it a function like you can with setState. In this case though, simply setting it to the inverse of `isToggled` will suffice, as you're not doing anything else that's based on that state.

Comment: firstly i am using prevSate to update setIsToggled and not to straight change property, i have updated my component with show atributes, and when i put ```handleOnClick={toggle}``` i get: TS2322: Type '{ onClickHandler: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.   Property 'onClickHandler' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

In `App.tsx`, instead of
`const [show, toggle]=useToggler();` you could write `const toggler = useToggler();` without deconstructing the array.

Then pass it down via props `<Header toggler={toggler} />` and `<DrawerToggleButton toggler={toggler} />`.

Finally in `DrawerToggleButton` access the onClick handler from `toggler[1]`

---

You could also just change `App.tsx` to pass down the toggle handler via `<Header toggle={toggle} />` and use the passed down props in `DrawerToggleButton` to get the `onClick` handler from `props.toggle`

Comment: when i put ```toggle={toggle}``` i get error: ``` TS2322: Type '{ toggle: [boolean, () => void]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.   Property 'toggle' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.```

Comment: `DrawerToggleButton` doesn't accept `props` as an argument, so you need it be able to receive a `toggler` of type [boolean, () => void]

Comment: I put it into a quick codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-cannon-bwt5i